# Can Hibernate map a Java Calendar object to an SQL TIMESTAMP column?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, timestamp

Can [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) map a Java [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object to an SQL [`TIMESTAMP`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5523) column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes:

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar calendar;
```

Comment: Does this translate the date to the calendar time zone?

Comment: I'd guess the timezone is the default timezone of the virtual machine.

Comment: Bozho, I'm afraid that link is broken.  I've raised a related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117249/what-time-zone-does-hibernate-use-when-it-reads-and-writes-a-java-calendar-object

Comment: @Derek Mahar it was down for a few minutes I guess. It's up now.

Comment: Bozho, thank you for the link to your article.  It seems that the key method is `TimeZone.setDefault()`, particularly when a developer is not permitted to change `-Duser.timezone` on the JVM command line.

Comment: Bozho, according to http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypefornon-defaultTimeZone, `TimeZone.setDefault()` is not the best solution because it changes the time zone for the entire JVM (or class loader) when all that you may want is to change the time zone for a particular `Calendar` to `TIMESTAMP` mapping.